# Truncate empy space from a raw dd image

Tags: images, dd, fdisk, resizing

I have a raw disk image I took using `dd` of a Ubuntu instance. The total disk size is **300 GB**, but only **5.5 GB** used.

Is there a way to resize the raw dd image down to **20 GB**, keeping all of the 5.5 GB of data, and just truncating empty blocks?

Answer (score 8):

Check for sector sizes:

```
sudo fdisk -l '/home/user/images/test.img'

Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00070424

Device                      Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/home/user/images/test.img1 *     2048   26623   24576   12M  e W95 FAT16
/home/user/images/test.img2      26624 7200767 7174144  3,4G 83 Linux
```

Use end number (7200767) as reference add 1 and * 512 like below:

```
sudo truncate --size=$[(7200767+1)*512] '/home/user/images/test.img'
```

Your file should be truncated

Comment: This method does truncate the file however, you'll also need to resize the partition, if I understand the OP correctly.

Comment: @MrMas this actually works fine as written, so long as you rewrite the truncated image back to a disk that has enough room for the full source filesystem size.

Comment: You could get `7200767+1` with `sudo blockdev --getsz /dev/mmcblk0` and `(7200767+1)*512` with `sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/mmcblk0` as example if you read an mounted partition

Comment: I found the sector output from parted helpful: `sudo parted '/home/user/images/test.img' 'unit s print'`.

Answer (score 4):

Since it is a raw image, it will always be exactly the same size as the instance you made it from. However, there are a few tricks you can use to achieve the same.

## Zeroing

Writing zeroes to the areas with unused space prepares it for compression that effectively reduces the size to less than the used space:

```
sudo mount -o loop instance.img /testmount
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/testmount/zero
sudo rm -f /testmount/zero
sudo umount /testmount
```

## Compression

Simply compressing the image will make it smaller, regardless if you zeroed it first:

```
gzip instance.img
```

or, for a more modern approach:

```
zstd -T0 instance.img
```

## Filesystem-aware imaging

If the image does not have to be raw (i.e. a representation of the block device rather than the content), you also have the option of using filesystem-aware tools to create the image. Zeroing is not needed in this case. For example, ZFS comes with built-in support for this, example with comression:

```
sudo zfs snapshot myvms/myinstance@myimage
sudo zfs send myvms/myinstance@myimage | zstd -T0 > instance.zfs.zst
```

Answer (score 0):

If the disk is GPT partitioned, the `truncate` option given by @Wessel will cause the petition table entries to go bad, and the file can't be used to mount as a loop device. I follow this method

1. Mount the disk image first as a loop device

```
sudo -i
udisksctl loop-setup -f disk.img
#notedown where its mounted
gparted /dev/loopxx
```

2. In the gparted UI add a new partition of 1MB size at the end, apply changes
3. Unmount the file `udisksctl loop-delete -b /dev/loopxx`
4. dump the partition table to a file `sfdisk -d disk.img > partitions.txt`
5. Find the last sector used `parted disk.img 'unit s print'`
6. Find the byte offset = (last sector used + 1) * 512
7. truncate the file `truncate -s offset disk.img`
8. Update partitions.txt  to reflect new state

```
Remove the last-lba line from the since it no longer valid
Remove last 1MB partition since we don't need it anymore
```

9. Restore the partition table `sfdisk disk.img < partitions.txt`